# Loop for adding user input to creating objects(C#)

Tags: c#, loops, class, object, for-loop

I'm setting up a console application that will take the input from the user and make a new object with my class "Items". But I want a loop there as well so the user can do multiple inputs, what kind of loop should I use and how does it works if I want the variable "foo" to change through the loop?

I've tried some for loops and I'm trying to put the "i" after "foo" but did't get it to work...

```
        Console.WriteLine("Write a item:");
        string item = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Write a price:");
        decimal price = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
        var foo = new Items(item, price);
        Console.Write(" {0} {1} ", foo.Item, foo.Price);
```

**Edit:**
Sorry, I was thinking I should simplify everything. My mistake!
Like one of the comment said, I want to store every object created at each iteration. Then showing it like a "shopping list" with the most expensive at the top and the cheapest item at the bottom.

***This is one of the things I've tried.*** (not a for loop but with the same concept of i++ and so on)

```
        do
        {
       Console.WriteLine("Insert items that you want to buy, when you are finnish, write 'done'");
        Console.Write("Insert a item: ");
            string item = Console.ReadLine();
            switch (item.ToLower())
            {
                case "done":
                    break;

                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Write a price:");
                    decimal price = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
                    var foo(i) = new Items(item, price);
                    Console.Write(" {0} {1} ", foo.Item, foo.Price);
                    break;
            }
            i++;
        } while (item != "done");

        //Then show the list in order
```

Comment: Do you want to store each object created at each iteration as well?

Comment: *"I've tried some for loops"* - Not according to the code you're showing us you haven't.  *"but did't get it to work"* - What was your attempt and what didn't work about it?  Currently you're asking "How do I write a loop in C#?"  This is generally answered by introductory tutorials on the language.  Stack Overflow does not seek to replace general tutorials.  If you have some code you've written which isn't working as expected in a specific way, we can help with that.  In what way is the code you're showing us not working?

Comment: Sorry for my lack of information. I did edit the post so maybe this makes more sense.
@David That was my mistake, what I am asking for is how to change the variable "foo" for every iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Surely the compiler is telling you about this syntax error:

```
var foo(i) = new Items(item, price);
```

The variable declaration is broken.  It *looks like* you're trying to create a series of numbered variables.  Any time you want to do this, what you *really* want is a collection.  Something like a `List<T>` for example.  You would declare the list *before* the loop, then *add to* the list within the loop.

You probably also want to declare your input variable before the loop.  And name your variables sensibly, this will help you understand and support your own code.  (For example, you should rename your `Items` class to `Item`.  Because it represents a single "item" object.)

Something like:

```
var items = new List<Items>();
var itemName = string.Empty;
do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Insert items that you want to buy, when you are finnish, write 'done'");
    Console.Write("Insert a item: ");
    itemName = Console.ReadLine();
    switch (itemName.ToLower())
    {
        case "done":
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("Write a price:");
            decimal itemPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
            var item = new Items(itemName, itemPrice);
            items.Add(item);
            break;
    }
} while (itemName != "done");

// Here you now have a list of items.  You can loop over that list for further logic, output, etc.
```

Comment: `var itemName = string.Empty;` and `i++` feels unnecessary. `itemName` is never checked until after it has been assign to a value and `i++` is never used.
But my compiler complains about the default: but only on your code but not mine, cant find why
Otherwise it feels like this is working, Thank you alot @David!

Comment: @SkillLevelBeginner: In that case remove the `i++` if you don't use it.  You can also move the `itemName` declaration inside the loop if you like, I haven't tested if that will still be in scope in the `while` condition check, but you'll find out when you try.

Comment: It was just the `break;` that was missing below `default:`.
Thank you for all help!

Answer (score 0):

You may try this also for create application using C#. You can define length for how many items you want to add. Here i have used 2 length to add item in cart.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
namespace StackQue
{
    class Sample
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dictionary<string, decimal> items = new Dictionary<string, decimal>();
            for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Write an item");
                string item = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Write an price");
                decimal price = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
                items.Add(item, price);
            }
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Item " + item.Key + " have price " + item.Value + ".");
            }
        }
    }
}
```